# How would the word "landing" be translated?

Tags: traducción

I'm currently writing an essay on the film Che, and I mention how it begins with the landing of Che and other revolutionaries in Cuba. However, I cannot find a proper translation of "landing" with respect to this context, only *aterrizaje*, which is used for plane landings I believe.

Could anyone give me a suitable translation for this word, or any alternatives?

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: @syrux el se esta refiriendo al desembarco del Granma.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would simply use "la llegada", if "it begins with the landing of Che and other revolutionaries in Cuba" is the actual sentence you want to translate.

Answer (score 9):

In the context of that specific moment when you arrive to some place on a boat or yacht the word would be:

> desembarco

to refer to the [Desembarco del Granma](http://www.cubahora.cu/historia/la-hazana-mas-heroica-de-la-historia)

**Granma** is the name of the yacht in which Fidel Castro, Che Guevara, Raúl Castro, and 79 of their supporters sailed from Mexico to Cuba in 1956 and incited the Cuban Revolution in 1959.

I'm Cuban.

Answer (score 3):

**la llegada** would be the proper translation, since it's an essay, I would use a more formal approach and go with **el arribo**.

Comment: "El arrivo" is wrong spelling. You mean "el arribo". I'd choose "El desembarco" however.

Comment: Completely right @betacentauri , I keep messing up thinking of "arrive", good catch.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are some different possible translations:

- **Desembarco**, *when it refers to a boat or sea ship*
- **Amerizaje**, *when it refers to any kind of ship*
- **Arribo**, *in case it's not actually a ship or vehicle which has came*

Comment: _Amerizaje_ is used when an aircraft lands on water (i.e. a seaplane) not when somebody lands from a boat in water into land. Similarly _Alunizaje_ for a spacecraft landing on the moon